# Errors on upgrading Laravel from 8 to 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-upgrade

some time ago I updated my local project from version 5 to 9, and everything works correctly. Now it's time to update the production version and I didn't want to reload the whole project, but to update as I did locally. A couple of months ago I upgraded from version 5 to 7.3. Today I updated to version 8.83, and I wanted to get to the latest version. The error it returns to me is the following:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php on line 488`

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance to all those who will help me.

Comment: try removing `vendor/` folder completely and try again.

Comment: Do I not lose any data if I delete the vendor folder?

Comment: The site becomes unreachable.

Comment: Laravel 9 requires PHP 8 you don't seem to have that in production

Comment: In production I have selected PHP 8.1, in cPanel. And then I verified that using command php -v

Answer (score 0):

Apokryfos was right. The general version was 7.4, and not being able to change it because it is the responsibility of the hosting, I contacted the support, who advised me to use a special command so that Composer could use the appropriate version of PHP.
Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).